# Word opens custom template with a blank page

Tags: microsoft-word, templates

I have 2 custom templates in Word that I created quite a few years ago. 1 of them still works. Unfortunately, the other one simply opens a blank page. It wasn't like that the last time I used it a couple of years ago. Strangely, opening it with Apple's equivalent 'Pages' doesn't pose any problem, so the data is still there.

But exporting or converting it in Pages as a Word document doesn't solve this issue. Opening the template via right-clicking doesn't make a difference, either. I suspect it might have to do something with 'compatibility mode' as that's what I can see next to the still working template name when I open it.

Is there a way to solve this issue? If possible, on a Mac.

Comment: It is possible that the entire document is inside a field construction. What happens if you press Opt+F9?

Comment: Do you mean alt+F9? That's what I can do on my apple keyboard. But nothing happens when I press it when I mark the document in Finder or when I opened the "blank" document.

Comment: No, I meant Opt+F9 assuming that you are on a Mac. You can also go into Word > Preferences and change the preference to view field codes in your preferences. *(The Windows command is Alt+F9. You may have to also press a Fn shift key with this.)* To see if the keyboard shortcut is working, create a new document and add a page number, which is a field. If field codes are being displayed it will show up as { PAGE } instead of a page number.

Comment: Yes, it works. And now the template works just fine, even after I've deselected "view field codes" again. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that the entire document is inside a field construction.

### What happens if you press Opt+F9?.

I am assuming that you are on a Mac. You can also go into Word > Preferences and change the preference to view field codes in your preferences. (The Windows command is Alt+F9.

You may have to also press a Fn shift key with this.)

To see if the keyboard shortcut is working, create a new document and add a page number, which is a field. If field codes are being displayed it will show up as `{ PAGE }` instead of a page number.